# Use Url.http for GET query

Tags: flutter, dart

In my browser it returns the correct json

```
http://localhost:8008/api/instsets/?genre=rock
```

Howeber in dart code

```
final response = await http.get(Uri.http('localhost:8008', 'api/instsets/?genre=rock'));
```

It returns 404 error.

Without query, it works,

```
final response = await http.get(Uri.http('localhost:8008', 'api/instsets'));
```

Where should I fix??

Comment: Do you get 404 from emulator/phone, or from same machine as browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/Uri.http.html), the `query` parameter should be an object and you should pass it to the function as the third argument. So in your case, the code will be:

```
final response = await http.get(Uri.http('localhost:8008', 'api/instsets', { genre: 'rock' }));
```

Comment: It works!!! thank you very much. `?query=value` doesn't work on `http.get`

Answer (score 0):

It is because it is on your localhost

localhost = 127.0.0.1

You have to point your local IP address instead of localhost

ex: http://192.168.1.101:8008   like this.

In case of laravel api,

```
php artisan serve --host=192.168.1.101
```

Comment: That might not be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

You included an extra `/` before your query.

You had `'api/instsets/?genre=rock'`

Instead of `'api/instsets?genre=rock'`, which (I think) is also the same result as using the `query` object.

APIs (at least the ones I use) are sensitive to trailing `/`s

e.g. if you created a `test-route`, calling

- `api/v1/test-route` would return `200`
- `api/v1/test-route/` would return `404`

Answer (score 0):

```
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://localhost:8008/api/instsets/?genre=rock'));
```

Comment: HI DiyorbekDev, can you explain a bit what your solution does? It may seem clear but less experienced users will profit from a short explanation (and the algorithm won't mark your answer as low-quality).